# How to avoid store VBox log files in home directory

Tags: virtualbox

I auto start vbox headless. When doing so VBoxSVC-1654.log files are generated in HOME folder.

How to avoid these, or to generate VBoxSVC log files in tmp folder instead of home

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've directly changed environment variables impacting VirtualBox, it looks like the creation of those files in that location may be an indication of something going wrong in VirtualBox (since they wouldn't otherwise be placed in your Home directory by default):

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=106236

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=104562

As far as diagnosing the specific issue in VirtualBox causing this, posting in those linked forums and sharing what's in those log files might get help faster, since they're dedicated to VirtualBox specifically.

Hope this helps,